# Spring Boot project depending on a spring project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

fair warning: I am new to Spring and maven.

The project:

The client has provided us with a web project that uses jsp to render front ends and uses spring-context only to manage some of their classes as Spring Beans. This project uses xml configuration. Here is the maven section that includes the spring-context:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Our job is to create an api layer for this project to open up access to the project's resources. The plan is to create a modern Spring Boot api using the spring-boot-web starter.

The problem:

The jsp project is split up into sub-modules. We are trying to take their business logic submodule as a maven dependency in our api project (it defines it's own spring context). The first problem that we have faced occurs when we simply add the module from the jsp project as a dependency in our api project. The spring boot initialization process provides no log feedback and hangs but does not exit (It runs fine when the dependency is not included). When crawling through with a debugger I have found that it is loading configuration files that are in the business module. My thinking is that one of the api's configuration files are getting overwritten which is breaking spring's logging and other behaviors.

The other more general problem is that I don't know if I can use the beans provided in the business logic module in my modern version of spring.

So the question is:

Is there a proper way to use beans defined in a dependent spring project?

Comment: IS the dependency a war file or a jar? Do you know what the unique package name for all the dependencies are?

Comment: @Pytry The dependency is a jar and we know all of the package names